# How to add context menu option for laying out the diagram in DSL Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dsl-tools

I would like to add an option to the DSL extension that I am creating in the Visual Studio DSL Tools (Visualization and Modeling SDK), to auto-arrange the layout via the context menu that appears when right-clicking on the diagram.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by first of all declaring a new command that appears in the context menu when right-clicking on the diagram, and by then writing the handler code for this to layout the diagram.

There's a very good guide to declaring and registering a new command on MSDN:  [How to: Add a Command to the Shortcut Menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820681.aspx)

The method needed layout the diagram is [AutoLayoutShapeElements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.modeling.diagrams.diagram.autolayoutshapeelements.aspx) on the `Diagram` class.

The following code will work for laying out the diagram (assuming you registered the method called `OnArrangeDiagramClick` as the event handler when overriding the `GetMenuCommands` method):

```
private void OnArrangeDiagramClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var selectedObject in CurrentSelection)
    {
        if (selectedObject is YourDslDiagram)
        {
            var diagram = (selectedObject as YourDslDiagram);
            using (var tx = diagram.Store.TransactionManager.BeginTransaction("ModelAutoLayout"))
            {
                diagram.AutoLayoutShapeElements(diagram.NestedChildShapes, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Diagrams.GraphObject.VGRoutingStyle.VGRouteStraight, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Diagrams.GraphObject.PlacementValueStyle.VGPlaceSN, false);
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```